# An employer is trying to force me to switch banks, which I know is illegal. What should I do?

Tags: united-states, legal, compensation, new-hires, payroll

An employer has extended a job offer with the condition that I switch my personal banking from one institution to another. They claim that they do this to simplify their internal payroll procedures. I happen to know that such requirements [are illegal](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/1693k), and that the employer is required to remain more flexible in regards to how they pay me. How should I proceed?

---

Some relevant info from OP comments:

> [The company has] nothing to do with banking at all

.

> I pointed out the guidelines they were supposed to follow when hiring within my state. On a conference call with a V.P. the other day they claimed that, since they have some employees that are outside of the U.S., they are "international" and therefore don't have to obey U.S. law, and that since I'm an individual I should be afraid to pursue this matter with any law enforcement, as they may be able to sue with a counterclaim for wasting their time

.

> I've been looking for positions in the same field and discovered there are businesses that appear legitimate but warn they will refuse to hire based on where an employee does their personal banking

[OP's Law SE question regarding the legality of the matter](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/can-an-employer-force-all-employees-to-open-bank-accounts-in-the-employees-name/42696#42696)
[OP's Law SE question regarding how to take action against this employer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/how-are-employer-pay-statutes-enforced-against-offending-employers?noredirect=1#comment88274_46142)

Comment: Is the employment offer for a position with the bank in question?  I once had a job offer with an authorized third party retailer for a major cell phone company that stipulated you switch to their cell phone service within a year of accepting the offer.

Comment: @ Joe Strazzere: The company does contract work for television stations. They have nothing to do with banking at all. I pointed out the guidelines they were supposed to follow when hiring within my state. On a conference call with a V.P. the other day they claimed that, since they have some employees that are outside of the U.S., they are "international" and therefore don't have to obey U.S. law, and that since I'm an individual I should be afraid to pursue this matter with any law enforcement, as they may be able to sue with a counterclaim for wasting their time. I think they're a fraud.

Comment: So... they are "international", but cannot transfer money inside the United States without problems? I'd run.

Comment: @ Joe Strazzere: How about a country lacking these sorts of violations?
I've been looking for positions in the same field and discovered there are businesses that appear legitimate but warn they will refuse to hire based on where an employee does their personal banking. This is actually fairly confusing for me, as that makes them look like a scam, but that's a lot of work to go to for a scam. Maybe the bank pays a commission?
After some digging online and a question on another Stack Exchange I've found out there is actually a federal agency that wants me to report this kind of violation.

Comment: @RegionalDirector "don't have to obey U.S. law"  err no not if they are in the USA they don't  - Just like USA companies have to obey the law in other countries.

Comment: Just to clarify, what does "switch my personal banking" mean? In your position, I'd probably have no objection to just opening a new account in the bank they recommend, and then transfer all the salary into my ordinary account. Provided they have decent online banking. But I don't live in the USA, so your circumstances may differ. If, however, they mean that you should literally close your current accounts and move everything over, no way.

Comment: Regardless of how this issue is resolved, a company hiring employees in the US that openly claims they do not have to obey US law and threatening retaliation for reporting violations is the biggest of red flags. What other laws do they plan to disobey? Minimum wage? Overtime? Tax withholding and payroll taxes? Workplace safety? Paying you at all? If this is how they treat you before you even start, how do they plan to treat you once you're on the job? Run.

Comment: Also asking for clarification: Are they asking you to *switch* or *open an account*? For perspective, here in Japan it's very common for part-time jobs to require an account with X Bank, because that's who their payroll is setup with. Following, it's also common for many people to have accounts with multiple banks

Comment: You may find your pay is delayed by an extra day if it is not the same bank. For cash flow purposes they may leave payroll to the last minute, similarly to paying accounts on 90 days and not before. A corporate connection may also be involved. I believe all Facebook employees have to have Facebook. In some countries your manager is informed if your cheques bounce as a bank employee, as you are supposed to be an upstanding member of the community.

Comment: How much do you want the job vs how important is a point of principle

Comment: Sometimes you encounter a red flag without knowing this particular problem even existed. Wow. Run, don't look back. This is not a company you want to work for.

Comment: My German employer insisted I get a German bank account, even though SEPA payments should be uniform within the Eurozone.  Maybe they just use very crappy software.

Comment: @gerrit Thereʼs a huge difference between requiring a bank with a national office and requiring a specific bank. Additionally, I think this requirement may relate to tax laws and tax evasion rather than SEPA, although Iʼm not sure if this makes this a valid requirement.

Comment: There *are* circumstances where an employee might legitimately be required to have an account with a particular bank.  I worked in IT for a financial company that was part of a bigger group that was part of one of the major UK banks, so we were all technically bank employees.  So I had to open a personal bank account with them, into which my salary was paid.  (I kept an account open at another bank too.)  Going overdrawn would have been a disciplinary matter!  But I did get a contactless debit card 6 months before the public… Dunno if they still do that, but it was all above-board.

Answer (score 40):

> How should I proceed?

Politely decline their offer and continue to search for a new company to work for.  If the reason for requiring you to switch banks is true, this is indicative of a whole department (arguably the most important for any employee) that doesn't seem to know what they're doing.  Definitely not a company worth working for.

Comment: Do you feel I have an obligation to see that the laws in question are properly enforced against the employer?

Comment: @RegionalDirector Do *you* feel that you have an obligation to see that the laws in question are properly enforced against the employer?  That sort of thing is a matter of personal ethics, and somewhat beyond the scope of this stack.

Comment: @RegionalDirector That is your call, if you feel strongly enough about this issue to pursue a legal avenue then go ahead.  I personally would just move on and be thankful that I dodged a bullet of what looks to be a bad company.

Comment: I'm not certain what the process would even be to enforce the laws against an employer. I've created a question on Law Stack Exchange ( https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/how-are-employer-pay-statues-enforced-against-offending-employers?noredirect=1#comment88274_46142 ) so that I can get more information on how I could proceed.

Comment: Money problems tends to change into much bigger problems.  The simplest is bankruptcy. The worst will lead to jail.

Answer (score 25):

Most likely a scam, especially if the company is online based. I'd review up to this point how you got the job. Did you go for an interview? Were you hired on the spot? Were all your paperwork done via email/telephone?

This scam is common. A fake company has you do what seems like work, then they "pay" you with a check with very specific instructions like what bank you use, what sort of account to open, to disclose account numbers, how to deposit the check, etc. The scam involves where some banks allow for small cash reserve to be available immediately, especially if you deposit a "pay check" in person. It's a small amount like $100, or $200. The fake company then withdraws this small amount immediately, then you get a bounced check notice. The bank will likely ask (either by courts or by making a bad mark on your credit) that you pay it back since "you" withdrawn it but you didn't and you can't prove it other than showing you deposit what you thought was a legit check.

My advice: don't even answer. Run.

Comment: This sounds like a good citizen would inform the authorities as well.

Comment: Yes, but it's very doubtful this is the person's first time doing this. Chances are the company is real but the scammer is using it as a disguise. The scammer could be anywhere in the world and may be finding all their information just by what is publically available. I would double check if you can by researching online. Maybe even calling the actual company to verify the person works there and that it is their policy to use a specific bank.

Comment: I have done that. The policy is a real one that exists at the actual business. I actually have another question you can find through my profile about what's going on in specific.

Comment: All indications to me makes this sound like an elaborate scam. I would be very hesitant in doing business with an "international" company. I don't know if it is purely online based, or if you are going to a physical work site, but I would caution that you should bail out of this and not proceed.

Comment: @RegionalDirector, So you called the number from their web site, that's good. But that is still no guarantee that it isn't a scam. Anyone can set up a legitimately looking web site these days. It's very easy.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Actually, no, that isn't how this happened. When looking for work I was referred by another company. Then someone at their company wound up calling me after I started vocalizing my concerns about the job requirements they'd posted. They reached out to me when they found out why I was not interested.

Comment: And maybe Call the FBI and Tip off Brian Krebs

Answer (score 6):

Advise them that you'll accept their job offer on the condition that they change their bank account to the same as yours.

If they respond with an answer such as "But that's ridiculous, that would be so inconvenient" then respond "Exactly".

Answer (score -8):

In US almost every employment is "At Will".

You have the right to decline it pursuant to your reasons, they have the right to rescind the offer pursuant to their

Especially, if you using different bank will cost company money.

If you really want that position, research the reason behind the switch request and argue according to that.

Weigh your pros and cons.

And be prepared to say NO and walk away from the offer.

Comment: I've had an insight that I can delete my comment and ask a related question instead. I will do that.

Comment: @RegionalDirector ok

Comment: "At will" empoyment has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: "At will" doesn't mean being allowed to do illegal stuff. Would you work for a company that does illegal things?

Comment: @Bebs Absolutely not, but then its not even a question, OP explained that when he called them up on request being illegal, they made up a excuse. In my book this a red flag and a deal breaker, so no ambiguity and reason for a question, dont you agree?

Comment: Yes I agree, that's why the question has been put on hold (I didn't downvote you by the way).

Comment: @Bebs Thank you for saying that :) any vote is reaction, i am ok with ever one, sometimes missing the comment thou :)